# Multiple repos with Angular Single Page Application

Tags: angular, lerna

So I have a single page application built using Angular 6 stored in git repo A. This app is using an external Angular packages which is maintain by different team stored in repo B, lets call it Lib. I also have edit access to Lib which contains shared resources for footer and header of the site.

Currently multiple Angular packages are inside Lib which is maintained using Lerna. The single page app only refer to the package and import it as a reference using package.json. Installed within the single page app using npm install Lib

Is there an easy way to enable debugging of this external package within the single page app? Maybe I can import is using specific Angular settings?

I am an Angular newbie. Ideas that's going around in my head is through 'git worktree' to import the Lib Angular src into the single page app directory. Maybe using simlink that basically reference external directory as it was within the single page app.

Comment: if you have access to edit both repo then may be you can look into https://github.com/nrwl/nx . It combines multiple angular repos into one calling it `mono workspace`.